# How to import directory of .scala files in sbt (unmanaged)?

Tags: scala, import, dependencies, sbt

I have a directory that I want to use as a dependancy for an sbt project however its comprised of .scala files which means I can't place it inside a jar (from what I understand) so then how can I use it as a dependancy for my project?
(sbt doesn't have it as a managed dependancy)
thanks in advance

Comment: `sourceDirectories += <your source dir>`

Comment: when I try that I get: 
error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], String] found,
  so String cannot be appended to Seq[java.io.File]

Comment: I meant using a file, not string. e.g: `sourceDirectories in Compile += file("/path/to/your/sources")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as written in [the manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory), you can customize the sources (or source directories) pretty freely. by default, sbt will expect to have scala and java sources under a source directory.
you can [customize that too](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Change+the+default+Scala+source+directory). depending on your exact use case, maybe you want these sources under a different configuration? if it's just extra sources to compile and package, you can simply use:

```
sourceDirectories in Compile += file("/path/to/your/sources")
```

or:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("/path/to/your/sources")
```

use the first when the sources are managed, e.g: if these sources are generated by some other program, or retrieved as a dependency, etc'...
use the second when these are plain sources not managed by anything.

Comment: Thanks Gilad,
one last thing, what do you mean by "depending on your exact use case, maybe you want these sources under a different configuration?"

Comment: Sbt Configurations are roughly analogous to maven scopes. So test sources are found under a different directory than your regular code. This means that `sourceDirectories in Test` refer to the source directories scoped to the Test configuration. If you have a "special" purpose for these files (e.g: generated sources from Antlr or sources retrieved via git) a custom configuration might be what you need.